# AWS CodeBuild Code Coverage supporting clover.xml

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, jestjs, devops, aws-codebuild

I'm trying to create two report groups for test and code coverage, the test group is working fine whereas my code coverage group is showing following error.
**Error in UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS phase: [arn:aws:codebuild:ap-south-1:831110728702:report-group/Lambdaunittest: [error creating report: InvalidInputException: Report group type doesn't match expected report type, report group type is TEST, but report type is CODE_COVERAGE]]**.
Any help or lead will really help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance. For more information please go through the attached screenshots.
[buildspec.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZW8FD.png)

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOGRg.png)

Comment: Just noting the group type name that you have used is .../Lambdaunittest.  Is this indeed configured as type TEST and not CODE_COVERAGE?

Comment: Hi @Norman yes i wanted as code_coverage. The mistake what i did, i chose group type as test and i tried and expecting for code coverage report. I have changed the group type to code coverage and it worked as expected. Thanks for the reply